# PHP uploads timeout even though php.ini is configured correctly

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Forgive my lack of PHP sophistication - I've confirmed that all my **php.info** settings are configured correctly for uploads of **300M**, but when I try to **upload a file over 128M** the submission **times out** at exactly 30 seconds:

> ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

my time limit, memory limit, execution time, etc are all working.  I'm on GoDaddy hosting is it possible my tmp folder size is limited?

Answer (score 0):

Put below line at top of script that hadles Upload,

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

This will override PHP default time limit of 30 secs. 0 means no time limit.
[read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Pinkal, still won't work. Do I need php.ini files in the temp folder and upload folder with appropriate values as well?